# A basic exercise about the temperature distribution in the cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

> Saturated steam $(h_s=10000 W/m^2K)$ at $110 ^\circ C$ flows inside a pipe $(k_p=400 W/mK)$ with an internal diameter of 10 cm and an external diameter of 12 cm. The pipe is located in a space at $30^\circ C$ and the heat transfer coefficient on its outer surface is estimated to be $15 W/m^2K$.
>
> Find the temperature distribution for uninsulated pipe and calculate the heat loss per length (W/m).

I would be glad if someone could check my work. Thanks!

**Attempt.**
Note that the temperature distribution is given by $$T(r)=\frac{T_{s,1}-T_{s,2}}{\ln(r_1/r_2)}\ln(r/r_2)+T_{s,2}.$$ where $T_{s,1}=T(r_1)$ and $T_{s,2}=T(r_2)$

In our case, $T(r_1)=383 K$ and $T(r_2)=303 K$. So, the temperature distribution is
$$T(r)=\frac{383-303}{\ln(0.05/0.06)}\ln(r/0.06)+303.$$

On the other hand, the heat transfer rate is given by the formula $$q_r=\frac{2\pi Lk(T_{s,1}-T_{s,2})}{\ln(r_2/r_1)}.$$ So, the heat loss per length becomes
$$q_r/L=\frac{2\pi 400(383-303)}{\ln(0.06/0.05)}.$$

Comment: You omitted the resistances to heat transfer from the steam to the inside wall of the pipe, and from the outside wall of the pipe to the surroundings.  The temperature at the inside wall of the pipe is not 383 K (it is lower), and the temperature of the outside wall is not 303 K (it is higher).